# Funding data for US Department of Education CSV format

Tags: usa, data.gov, government, education

I am looking for data about the funding from the Department of Education, Energy and Defense. The data I want is the fund/award number, the PI, Co-PI (if any) and the award amount along with the year of the grant.

I searched in data.gov but could not find. Any suggestions as to where I can get this data.

Answer (score 3):

If the data you need is from more recent years, USAspending.gov is a good place to start (you can choose a specific agency on the data download page: https://www.usaspending.gov/DownloadCenter/Pages/DataDownload.aspx).

Depending on the type of research you're doing, it might be important to note that the federal funding amounts displayed on USAspending represent *obligated dollars* (*e.g.*, money that's been set aside for an award), which doesn't always equal the money that's actually spent (*e.g.*, outlayed).

Some smaller awards are excluded from USAspending. Details: https://www.usaspending.gov/about/Pages/TheData.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links. Is there any place where we can get the actual money spent? For example, we can get the information for National Science Foundation at http://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/download.jsp

Comment: There's no single data source that reports actual federal money spent at the award level. In fact, the NSF link above looks to be reporting award amounts, not actual dollars spent (which should match amounts reporting on USAspending).